# Multiline UILabel sometimes displays fully, sometimes cuts off

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikit, ios-autolayout

Since the release of iOS 8 I've been experiencing a strange issue on a review display View where my long, multiline titles don't always display with the full title on screen. What makes this problem more frustrating is that the display is inconsistent, sometimes displaying the full title, and other times cutting it off like so:

[image: Cut off title screenshot]
[image: Fully displayed title screenshot]

In my ViewController, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Since we have multi-line labels, do an initial layout pass and then set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth
    // based on their width so they will wrap text and take on the correct height
    [self.cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.cell.titleLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.cell.contentView.frame)];
    [self.cell.titleLabel sizeToFit];

    [self.cell.descriptionLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.cell.contentView.frame)];
    [self.cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];

    return self.cell;
}
```

The relevant portion of `init` in my View code looks like this:

```
 // title label
    self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[StringFactory defaultFontType] size:kTitleFontSize]];
//    if (self.review.title)
//    {
//        [self.titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", self.review.title]];
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        [self.titleLabel setText:@""];
//    }
    [self.titleLabel setText:@"\"This title should be too long to fit on one line. If it isn't, we have bigger problems.\""];
    [self.titleLabel setTextColor:[ColorFactory CC333]];
    [self.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    [self.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [self.titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.titleLabel setBackgroundColor: [ColorFactory CCOrange]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
```

And here is the constraint setting (using Masonry):

```
typeof (self) __weak weakSelf = self;

// title
[self.titleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_top).with.offset(kPadding);
    make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_left).with.offset(kPadding);
    make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_right).with.offset(-kPadding);
}];

[self.ratingBubbles mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(weakSelf.titleLabel.mas_bottom).with.offset(5);
    make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_left).with.offset(kPadding);
    make.height.equalTo(weakSelf.bubbleHeight);
    make.width.equalTo(weakSelf.bubbleWidth);
}];

[self.dateLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(weakSelf.titleLabel.mas_bottom).with.offset(5);
    make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.ratingBubbles.mas_right).with.offset(kPadding);
    make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_right).with.offset(-kPadding);
}];


// description
[self.descriptionLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(weakSelf.ratingBubbles.mas_bottom).with.offset(5);
    make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_left).with.offset(kPadding);
    make.right.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_right).with.offset(-kPadding);
    make.bottom.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_bottom).with.offset(-kPadding);
}];
```

I've been trying to find a fix for this for the past two months or so, on and off, but haven't had any luck so far. If anyone out there has experienced a similar issue, please post your experiences.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the new self-sizing cell api?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not familiar with it. Fairly new to iOS in general. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the self-sizing cell api. As long as your cell is set up correctly with constraints, all you need to do is add a couple of lines in `viewDidLoad`,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // this may or may not be necessary I found that cells didn't size correctly until scrolled or rotated without this line in iOS 8.3
}
```

Your constraints need to be continuous from the top of the cell through any views to the bottom. You don't need any of the code you currently have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`; the only thing you should do there, other than dequeuing the cell, is set the label's text. In the cell class, you don't need `sizeToFit`, and you shouldn't be setting the text there.

Comment: Is self-sizing cell API a native objective-c library, or do I need to install a cocoa pod?

Comment: @Matt, it's native. There's a WWDC video about it, I think from 2014.

Comment: Question for you. What would cause this behavior in the first place? The images in the post are from the exact same code running the same simulation. I tap on a review, display it, tap back, and then tap on the review to display it again. Same action, different result.

Comment: @Matt, some layout operations are happening when you move back and forth between the views, so something must be being updated when you do that.

Comment: Any recommendations as to where I should look to debug this? `loadView`? `viewDidLoad`? `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Matt debug what? I'm not sure what you're doing at this point. Is the self-sizing cells method I proposed not working for you?

Comment: Self-sizing isn't working. Seeing the same issue. I've submitted the problem to Apple Developer support, so maybe someone over there will be better able to assist. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Yes self-sizing cell can help you with this as rdelmar mentioned. One key thing to note is that the uilabel should have autolayout constraints set properly and also the number of lines should be set to 0.